# moving a image with the mouse in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i have made some code that moves a image (using the mouse) called bulb using pygame but when i move it to the left hand side at the bottom of the screen it gets suck and cant be picked back up again any help would be amazing thank you very much

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 800

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) #make the display
pygame.display.set_caption("car game") #title of the window
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  #frames per second defined here

bulb = pygame.image.load("bulb.png")

def bulbfunc(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(bulb, (x,y))


def mainloop():
    gameExit = False
    mouseDown = False
    x = width - 170
    y = 20
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get(): #when any action is done by the user
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        bulbfunc(x,y)
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.update()


        clickstatus = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        (xs, ys) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if mouseDown == False:
            if (x - 45) < xs < (x + 45) and (y - 45) < ys < (x + 45):
                print("true")
                print(x)
                if clickstatus[0] == 1:
                    mouseDown = True

        if mouseDown == True:
            if clickstatus[0] == 1:
                (x, y) = (xs, ys)
            else:
                mouseDown = False



mainloop()
pygame.exit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in this line:

```
if (x - 45) < xs < (x + 45) and (y - 45) < ys < (x + 45)
```

It should be:

```
if (x - 45) < xs < (x + 45) and (y - 45) < ys < (y + 45)
```

Note it's (y + 45) at the end instead of (x + 45)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a line of code like this:

```
if (x - 45) < xs < (x + 45) and (y - 45) < ys < (x + 45):
```

I assume you mean to have the last condition as `(y + 45)`. This would explain it getting stuck at the left hand side at the bottom, where `ys` is large and `x` is small, so the second condition is never fulfilled. Copy and pasting can be dangerous if you aren't careful!